# Java process suddenly stops on Linux Hyper-V VM

Tags: java, linux, orientdb

I am running an [OrientDB](http://orientdb.com/) database on a CentOS 7 Hyper-V VM. The VM has 4 Cores and 4 GB RAM.

My problem is, that the OrientDB Java process stops unexpectedly and I can't find the problem because I can't find any error logs.

I've already checked the kernel logs (/var/log/messages), dmesg (/var/log/dmesg), journalctl and the OrientDB logs. None of these logs show me any errors.

I have the dull feeling that there is some OOM problem, but I can't find any proof for it. Also, top tells me that there should be enough memory and as long as I am monitoring the VM, memory consumption seams to be fine.

So, can anybody give me some advice where I can get hints what happened to the Java process? There is also a Tomcat running (also a Java process) without any problems.

Comment: I guess you're running orientDb 2.2.x. The server starts by default with 2G of heap and  4G of disk cache (direct memory). Don't know how much heap is dedicated to tomcat, but I think you don't have enough memory for all. Try to run OrientDB  with server.sh, so the log will be on the shell.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We have updated the memory of the server to 8 GB. Let's see if this will solve the problem. But nevertheless, I am very amazed that I can't find any logs that tell me that the Java process was killed.

Comment: BTW, can you detail more? Used version, how orient is started, database size, workload? If you are running as service, stop it and try to run the server on an interactive shell using ORIENTDB_HOME/bin/server.sh and report what happens.

Comment: Hi Roberto, sure. Version is 2.2.19, the database size is 36 MB on the HD and about 1000 Vertices and 1000 Edges. I always start orient with the server.sh start script. Before we upgraded to 8 GB RAM everything was INFO except one log: `WARNI Not enough physical memory available for DISKCACHE: 3.783MB (heap=1.963MB direct=524.288MB). Set lower Maximum Heap (-Xmx setting on JVM) and restart OrientDB. Now running with DISKCACHE=256MB [OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer]`. After the upgrade there are no warnings anymore except "Authenticated clients can execute ...".

Answer (score 0):

please update to 2.2.20 fix. I suppose that your problems are caused by the bug (direct memory leak) which we have fixed in given release.

Comment: Thanks Andrey for your reply, we will update to 2.2.20 soon. Also, the upgrade to 8 GB RAM seamed to temporary fixed the crashes. Nevertheless, it would be nice if the Exception/Error that stops the Java process would be logged. As I mentioned in my question, there is nowhere a hint what happened. So, it is really hard to understand what's going on.

Comment: Josef, we can not log it because OS kills the process when it reaches some memory limit of consumption. It is out of our control.

Comment: Okay, I thought that at least a OutOfMemoryError will be thrown in that case.

Comment: If the oom killer of the operative system kills the java process, doesn't mean the java process is in oom itself. If it is what happened.

Comment: Understood. Now I setup a new VM (again with 4 GB RAM) and the latest version of OrientDB (2.2.20). Again the Java process dies without any logs. I guess this is not your fault, but I am so astonished that there is no log from the Linux OOM killer.